# Making an array of matrices into array of triples of matrices / Python Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matrix

I have 891 matrices of size 7X32 together in an array. I would like to get 891 triples of matrices of size 7X32.

Example of two matrices (not that size obviously):

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
[[2,2,2,2,2],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]]
```

I need it to become:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
[[1,1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
[[1,1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
[[2,2,2,2,2],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
[[2,2,2,2,2],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
[[2,2,2,2,2],
[2,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,3,3,3]],
```

where [] means it's a different matrix.

The code I used to get the matrices:

```
matrices = np.dstack([df.values.astype(int)] * 32)
```

from a regular dataframe.

I thought maybe

```
matrices = np.dstack([[df.values.astype(int)] * 32]*3)
```

would work, but it didn't.

I'm doing this to try to make a regular problem into a 'image' like the cifar 10 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your original dataframe, this seems to work.  However, I'd defer to  @Divakar's advice if he produces what you need.

As for my solution, I'm sure there is a better way, but this worked.  This might even give @Divakar what he needs to see in order to show us all a better way.

```
np.stack([np.dstack([df.values.astype(int)] * 32)] * 3).transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Embarked': [0, 1, 1, 3, 1],
    'Family': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    'Fare': [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    'Pclass': [3, 1, 3, 1, 3],
    'Sex': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    'Title': [0, 3, 2, 3, 1]}
)['Pclass Sex Fare Embarked Title Family'.split()]
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: Pay attention to @Divakar's answer as he may edit it.  If he runs this solution and gets a clear idea of what you wanted, he may then have a better answer than this.  If he does, it would likely better for you.  So just keep your eye out.

Comment: I will keep an eye out, thanks! With this missing part of code I am trying to do a topological map from regular problems to image type to solve with CNN. Huge help!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) after extending by one more dim/axis -

```
np.repeat(a[None],3,axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [140]: a
Out[140]: 
array([[7, 1, 8, 6],
       [5, 8, 1, 1],
       [2, 7, 3, 7]])

In [141]: np.repeat(a[None],3,axis=0)
Out[141]: 
array([[[7, 1, 8, 6],
        [5, 8, 1, 1],
        [2, 7, 3, 7]],

       [[7, 1, 8, 6],
        [5, 8, 1, 1],
        [2, 7, 3, 7]],

       [[7, 1, 8, 6],
        [5, 8, 1, 1],
        [2, 7, 3, 7]]])
```

We can also use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) -

```
np.broadcast_to(a[None],(3,) + a.shape) # creates a read-only version
```

To make a writeable version, append with `.copy()`.

---

Using the history between OP and @piRSquared and also the answer post, here's my *dart in the wind* -

```
a = df.values.astype(int)
shp = a.shape
out = np.broadcast_to(a[:,None,:,None], (shp[0], 3, shp[1], 32))
```

Comment: I need to do it for an array of matrices, not just one. A single matrix was an example to help visualization of the problem.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz Well the question would be - How do you have that array of matrices stored?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for my poorly made example. I have just changed it for better interpretation. @Divakar

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz Still not clear. Can you make a runnable code that produces that "array of matrices"? Like `np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,4))` for 3D array and so on?

Comment: I have put it now exacly how I have it (for a 2 matrix example)